# Can we convert standalone JavaFX application to WAR?

Tags: javafx, javafx-8

We've a stand alone application developed using JavaFX technology. Now we have a requirement to make it accessible using browser from remote machines(basically a web-app). I'm just wondering if there is any way to convert the said JavaFX application to war file so that it can be  deployed on the web server.  Any pointers would be appreciated.

Comment: You should be able to run a JavaFX application either as Applet or using Java WebStart. What have you tried? Where did you have issues?

Answer (score 1):

A JavaFX based Application is an application that is running on a desktop. It's no server application that needs an application container or something. Therefore you should not build a WAR file.
By default you can't run JavaFX applications in a browser. You could use applet technology or webstart but this is a workflow that will create problems - wrong JRE version on client, etc. ([Java Applets - is it a wrong choice today?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11495557/java-applets-is-it-a-wrong-choice-today)).
The best way to build and share a JavaFX application is by creating an executable JAR or a native application / bundle (http://code.makery.ch/library/javafx-8-tutorial/part7/).
There are some prototypes that can be used to render JavaFX in the browser (by using HTML5 Canvas) but I would not use

Comment: What's wrong with a war file deployment of a website which provides web start for an FX client in a standardized enterprise environment?