# Java SWT Application to Web Application

Tags: java, php, jsp, jar, swt

For a project, I have to convert a large Java application with an SWT GUI into a web application. Does anyone have any recommendations on starting a project like this? Some ideas I've had are:

- Java Play
- Java Server Pages
- JWebSocket
- PHP/Java bridge

Also, one of the problems is that I only have access to the JAR file for the application and need to run it with parameters from a terminal. Would this be possible from one of the options listed above?

I appreciate any help you can provide!

Comment: Look at [Eclipse RAP](https://www.eclipse.org/rap/)

Comment: Take a look into [applets](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_applet_basics.htm).

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions. The only thing with using Applets is that the application is extremely large and uses SWT so everything would have to be converted and the project is very time sensitive. I will definitely look into both methods!

Comment: @KDOT [Java applets are pretty much dead](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33524663). Modern browsers just don't support them anymore. Eclipse RAP, as mentioned before, will be the best choice for you.

Comment: Thank you everyone for your help! I was able to pretty easily run the Java SWT application using Eclipse RAP (after a couple of hours of compatibility fixes).